# How to modify a Python JSON objects array

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7

Let's assume the following :

```
sp_sample=[{"t":1434946093036,"v":54.0},{"t":1434946095013,"v":53.0},{"t":1434946096823,"v":52.0}
```

I wish I could get the following result :

```
sp_sample=[{"t":1434946093036,"v":5400.0},{"t":1434946095013,"v":5300.0},{"t":1434946096823,"v":5200.0}
```

In other words, I wish I could iterate through the array and multiple v by a 100 factor.

The following only performs the multiplication on the first item, ie yields 54000 :

```
for i, a in enumerate(sp_sample):
    a[i]['v'] =  a[i]['v'] * 100
```

The `sp_sample` is of type tuple. Using the following yields the whole array, which is not what I expect :

```
print sp_sample[0]
```

Also, tried printing sp_sample :

```
print sp_sample
```

Which returns the following (replaced the ....... for brevity) :

```
([{'t': 1434946093036, 'v': 54.0}, {'t': 1434946095013, 'v': 53.0}, {'t': 1434946096823, 'v': 52.0}, {'t': 1434946098612, 'v': 52.0}, {'t': 1434946100400, 'v': 51.0}, {'t': 1434946102372, 'v': 49.0},........, {'t': 1434947987823, 'v': 15.0}, {'t': 1434947989851, 'v': 12.0}, {'t': 1434947991899, 'v': 10.0}, {'t': 1434947993744, 'v': 5.0}, {'t': 1434947995599, 'v': 0.0}, {'t': 1434947997455, 'v': 0.0}, {'t': 1434947999494, 'v': 0.0}, {'t': 1434948001542, 'v': 0.0}, {'t': 1434948003417, 'v': 0.0}, {'t': 1434948005264, 'v': 0.0}, {'t': 1434948007120, 'v': 0.0}],)
```

print type(sp_sample) returns :

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply iterate over the list and update the dictionaries as you go:

```
sp_sample = [{"t":1434946093036,"v":54.0},{"t":1434946095013,"v":53.0},{"t":1434946096823,"v":52.0}]

for d in sp_sample:
    d['v'] *= 100

>>> print(sp_sample)
[{'t': 1434946093036, 'v': 5400.0}, {'t': 1434946095013, 'v': 5300.0}, {'t': 1434946096823, 'v': 5200.0}]
```

This will bind in turn each dictionary in list (tuple?) `sp_sample` to `d`, which you then update in place. You do not need to use `enumerate()`.

Note that you really need to multiply by 100, not 10000, to achieve the output that you have shown.

---

**Update**

`sp_sample` is actually a tuple with a list of dictionaries as its only item. So you need to access the list in the tuple like this:

```
sp_sample = ([{"t":1434946093036,"v":54.0},{"t":1434946095013,"v":53.0},{"t":1434946096823,"v":52.0}],)

for d in sp_sample[0]:    # N.B. access first item of tuple
    d['v'] *= 100
>>> print(sp_sample)
[{'t': 1434946093036, 'v': 5400.0}, {'t': 1434946095013, 'v': 5300.0}, {'t': 1434946096823, 'v': 5200.0}]
```

Or, since the tuple contains only a single item you could just get rid of the tuple by:

```
sp_sample = sp_sample[0]
for d in sp_sample:
    d['v'] *= 100
```

Comment: Python returns the following : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gear_add_10.py", line 20, in <module>
    d['v'] *= 100
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Then `sp_sample` is a list of lists, not a list of dictionaries as one would expect from the sample data in your question. Perhaps you could try printing the value of `sp_sample` before entering the update loop and double check the data types.

Comment: If `sp_sample` is in fact a list of lists, then you would need to change your code to `for item in sp_sample`: item[1] *= 100`.

Comment: I have the feeling that according to Python, the array is one item long, it looks like it unable to understand embedded objects.

Comment: From the update to your question you seem to have a tuple with a single list item, which is a list of dictionaries. So changing your code to: `for d in sp_sample[0]:
    d['v'] *= 100` should fix it.